# How do I write my ajax code to move from razor view to another?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-ajax

In my Save button ajax code I'm looking to redirect back to another razor page if a  successful save occured. How would I do that?

```
 function SaveEvent(data) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/StorageRequests/SaveEvent',
                data: data,
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.status) {
                        //Refresh the calender
                        FetchEventAndRenderCalendar();

                        $('#myModalSave').modal('hide');
                        alert('Thank you for your delivery time!');
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('Failed');
                }
            })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window.location.href

```
 if (data.status) {
                        //Refresh the calender
                        FetchEventAndRenderCalendar();

                        $('#myModalSave').modal('hide');
                        window.location.href='/{your razor page url relative to website root}';
                    }
```